# GDM does not prompt for password and doesn't let me log in

Tags: 11.04, login, gdm

Running Natty Beta 1. On install I set it to auto login because I was just playing around and testing.  Now I'm using the computer a little and decided to turn off auto-login. The next time I booted I get to the login screen, click my name, and just get a plinking sound and no prompt for a password. The options that appear in the bottom panel when you normally enter a password blink then disappear.

I can hit CTRL-ALT-F2 and log in via text mode but don't know where to go to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In text mode edited

/etc/gdm/custom.conf

setting `AutomaticLoginEnable=true`

Now at least it will log in automatically